# Cerebral palsy and IELTS

Tags: immigration, medical, language-test, education-visa

I'm suffering from Cerebral palsy and I want to participate in IELTS exam, but as I have certain problems like: missing the lines while reading, being slow in writing and having spasm attacks during the exam, I'm really worried if I can make it or not. Therefore, I'm wondering if anybody who has Cerebral palsy and has taken this exam could share his or her experience with me in order to help me out.

Anyways, tnx guys. I'm waiting for response.

Comment: Sorry, SE sites are not about *sharing experiences*, but strictly *Question and answer*. Can you [edit] your question so that it asks something answerable, e.g. *Are there special provisions for people with handicap/diseases/limitations to take an IELTS exam?*

Comment: You can request special arrangements before you take the test There is some information that may help here https://www.ielts.org/book-a-test/special-requirements

Comment: @Traveller that would be a good answer, with the link as well as some of the content.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t have personal experience to draw on, however the IELTS website states that its test centres have a number of ways to help test takers with special requirements. For example, you can request a modified version of IELTS, or special arrangements to be made, e.g. extra time, by giving the test centre notice. https://www.ielts.org/book-a-test/special-requirements

You should contact your local test centre to discuss your circumstances and find out how they can help you to take the test.
Good luck!!

Edit: The information is under ‘Learning difficulties’ https://www.ielts.org/book-a-test/special-requirements/learning-difficulties There is also an online enquiry form you can use to ask for more information eg help finding a local test centre which can accommodate your needs https://www.ielts.org/info-pages/contact-us/online-enquiry-form