# I need specific details about ielts test special requirements

Tags: immigration, canada, accommodation, ielts, regulations

I'm a 28 year old man who is suffering from Cerebral Palsy and I'm looking for an expert guy in the filled of ielts test special requirement as my condition is somehow unique due to problems like: missing the lines while reading, being slow in writing and having spasm attacks. In fact, I'm bring this up because when I read the papers, I didn't see any section related to my status.

It's really hurtful for me being in this type of a situation specially, when I see myself in love with English. It's been almost 9 years that i'm studying this language with passion and with my heart, hoping that someday I get to immigrate and jump off to my dream land. Right now, i'm a English translator who has also studied Spanish literature in uni. I'm felling like a bird in cage really these days, wondering how I can fly and make my way through IELTS.

Anyways, tnx guys. I would be very pleased if one expert can help with ielts test special requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The information is under ‘Learning difficulties’ https://www.ielts.org/book-a-test/special-requirements/learning-difficulties There is an online enquiry form you can use to ask for more information eg help finding a local test centre which can accommodate your needs https://www.ielts.org/info-pages/contact-us/online-enquiry-form

I have edited my answer to your first question [Cerebral palsy and IELTS](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15728/cerebral-palsy-and-ielts/15731#15731) to include the above

Comment: I don't know how to thank u!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @alireza kianpour If you’re happy with the answer, please ‘accept’ it. Thanks!

Comment: There is one more thing that I want to ask from u. Do u know anything about exemption? I mean is it possible that for example, I get an exemption for my writing task?

Comment: @alireza kianpour I’m not an expert in IELTS but IMHO no, it’s unlikely you’d get an exemption for an entire element of the test except possibly in the most exceptional of circumstances. You should contact the organisation to ask questions specific to your situation

Comment: tnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx